# How to Expose Objective-C Pointer Method WithResultBuffer in IOS Binding

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to Invoke Objective-C Method

```
   -(nabto_status_t)nabtoRpcInvoke:(NSString *)url withResultBuffer:(char 
    **)jsonResponse;
```

I used Objective-Sharpie Tool to generate the follow Method

```
 [Export("nabtoRpcInvoke:withResultBuffer:")]
 unsafe nabto_status_t RpcInvoke(string url, ref byte jsonResponse);
```

Please help expose me it correctly so i can get the JsonResponse String which i can use in IOS app.

Comment: you're using iOS Frameworks or Xamarin.iOS library bindings?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.IOS library bindings.

Comment: just be Clear Objective-sharpie generated 
         [Export("nabtoRpcInvoke:withResultBuffer:")]
         unsafe nabto_status_t RpcInvoke(string url, sbyte jsonResponse);  I i added the ref to get the output from pointer. as its char**

Comment: This Function is Called in Swift as   var buffer: 
                UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? = nil
                 let status = self.nabto.nabtoRpcInvoke(link, withResultBuffer: 
                 &buffer)  Now i need make it worked in Xamarin IOS Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Made these changes to Generated Method

```
 [Export("nabtoRpcInvoke:withResultBuffer:")]
        unsafe nabto_status_t RpcInvoke(string url, ref IntPtr 
       jsonResponse);
```

and then I got the JsonResonse as follow.

```
        IntPtr buff=new IntPtr() ;
        status = Client.RpcInvoke(URL, ref buff);

        byte[] newArray = new byte[buff.ToInt32() + 1];

        for (int m = 0; m < buff.ToInt32(); m++)
        {
            byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(buff,m);
            newArray[m] = b;
        }


        var JsonResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newArray);
```